# Batch APEX callout, Related record created, DML update to scope fails?

Tags: apex, batch, callout, dml

I have a batch process that I am using to send SMS notifications. In the execute method, I am making the callout, creating a log record and then updating scope. When I try to update scope, the record is not updated and the log record fails. If I run without updating scope, log is created as desired. My problem is that I need the scope records to up date to show that a message was sent. I've tried various patterns, but here is the basic outline:

```
Global class Messagebatch implements Database.batchable<sObject>,
Database.stateful,Database.allowscallouts{

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT ID,firstname,lastname,cellphone__c,phone,needs_sms__c FROM Account WHERE needs_sms__c = true LIMIT 25');
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){

 //list to hold logs to be inserted after loop
 list<messagelog__c>messagelist= new list<messagelog__c>();

     for (Account acc : scope) {
         acc.needs_sms__c=false;

     //class to send message here called here
     //after message sent, create a record
     messagelog__c log = new messagelog__c();

     //fill object with response data and add to list for insert
     messagelist.add(log);

    }//end of loop
    insert messagelist;
    update scope;

}//end of execute method
```

My problem is that when I update scope, the message logs are not created AND scope is not updated. When I remove the "update scope;" line, message records are created correctly. I tried to call another batch in the finish method to do the update, but was not successful with this approach. My end goal here is to simply uncheck the "needs_sms__c" check box to stop a duplicate message from being sent. The messages are sent successfully each time, but I need a way to update the record after a message has been sent. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a lookup from your log object to `Account`?

Comment: Yes, i have a lookup on the message log object looking at Account. I fill the value after the message is sent. "log.client__c = acc.id" and then added to the messagelist for insert.

Answer (score 1):

Go with following approach:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){

 //list to hold logs to be inserted after loop
 list<messagelog__c>messagelist= new list<messagelog__c>();

     for (Account acc : scope) {
         acc.needs_sms__c=false;

     //class to send message here called here
     //after message sent, create a record
     messagelog__c log = new messagelog__c();

     //fill object with response data and add to list for insert
     messagelist.add(log);

    }//end of loop
    try
    {
        insert messagelist;
    }
    catch(Exception ex {
         System.debug(' => messageList '+ex.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
        update scope;
    }
    catch(Exception ex {
         System.debug(' => scope '+ex.getMessage());
    }
}//en
```

> `Try catch` are added for investigation purpose if any of the
>   `system.debug` is printed so, you have found the reason why you could
>   n't update. My doubt is there is some issue in your DML
>   statement.

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to simply query for only `Account` records which have no child `MessageLog__c`.

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Needs_SMS__c = true AND Id NOT IN (
            SELECT Client__c FROM MessageLog__c
        )
    ]);
}
```